# Print hex or decimal values of byte array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c++, char, byte

I have a function in JavaScript which is expecting a byte array to be passed into it from Native C++ code. For example:

```
function OnEvent(event, data1)
{
     console.log("data1[0] = " + data1[0]);
}
```

I would like for it to print 0x55 or even the decimal value of it. For some reason, I am seeing the following in the console log:

[image]

How can I print the hex value of the byte or even the decimal value without printing the character?

---

**UPDATE**

I went to the link below thanks to Vinothbabu. I used the unpack function:

```
function unpack(str) { 
    var bytes = []; 
    $("#homePage").append("str.length = " + str.length + "<br>"); 

    for(var i = 0, n = str.length; i < n; i++) { 
        var char = str.charCodeAt(i); 
        $("#homePage").append("char is equal to " + char + "<br>"); 
        bytes.push(char >>> 8, char & 0xFF); 
    }

    return bytes; 
}
```

It prints "char is equal to 65533" and the value of "bytes" prints out "255, 253" which means it has a value of 0xFFFD.

This is not the data/payload that I was expecting. Do you know why there are 2 bytes?

Comment: Try data1[0].toString(16)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/pack-and-unpack-bytes-to-strings

Comment: Thanks Vinothbabu. I followed your link related to packing/unpacking. However, using unpack(): `code` function unpack(str) {
    var bytes = [];
    $("#homePage").append("str.length = " + str.length + "<br>");
    for(var i = 0, n = str.length; i < n; i++) {
        var char = str.charCodeAt(i);
        $("#homePage").append("char is equal to " + char + "<br>");
        bytes.push(char >>> 8, char & 0xFF);
    }
    return bytes;
}`code`    It prints "char is equal to 65533" and the bytes prints out 255, 253, which means it has a value of 0xFFFD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this will do the trick:

```
console.log("data1[0] = " + data1[0].toString(16));
```